# MVC 4 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Surname'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I get the following error when running the on a remote server. On the local IIS it works fine.

error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for  'Surname' and no extension method 'Surname' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Model - (in a seperate project)

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Names")]
    public string FirstNames { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var applicationForm = new ApplicationForm();
        ApplicationFormInfo.LoadInfoMembers();     

        return View(applicationForm);
    }
```

View

```
<%@ Control  Language="C#"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<USB_ED.Models.ApplicationF orm>" %>                
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="hideLegend"></legend>
            <label for="course"><strong>Select Course</strong></label>
            <select id="course"></select>
    </fieldset>

     <fieldset id="personalInformation">
            <legend>Personal Information</legend>        
            <div class="studentDetails fieldRow inline">
                <table>
                    <colgroup>  
                        <col style="width:auto"/>
                        <col style="width:180px"/>
                        <col style="width:auto" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname) %></td>
                        <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname) %></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Surname) %></td>
                    </tr>
```

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please    visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
          -->
        <configuration>
          <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
          </namespaces>
            </pages>
          </system.web>
          <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <!--<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"   culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234"   newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>-->
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234"  newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"      publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
          </runtime>
        </configuration>
        </pre>
```

The remote server and local machine has MVC 4 and Dot Net Framework 4.5 installed installed.
My Model is in a seperate project. I suspect the issue is in either the remote IIS or in the web.config file. Can you please help?

Comment: I assume you have a `@model` directive in your view ... ?

Comment: @model is used with Razor. I am using an ASPX form and has the following: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<USB_ED.Models.ApplicationForm>" %>

Comment: The app is installed on a Server 2008 R2 machine running IIS 7.5